# Update a model by unchecking a checkbox with a directive

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

So what I'm trying to make is a dependency with checkboxes. So that dependent checkbox will be disabled + unchecked once the checkbox that it is dependent upon is uncheck. For some reason, unchecking the checkbox from inside a directive does the job, as in disabling and unchecking it but the model that is binded to it does not update.

HTML:

```
<div>
  <input type="checkbox" data-ng-model="test.dependency"/>
  <span>unchecking this one will disable the next</span>
</div>

<div>
  <input dependent="test.dependency" type="checkbox" data-ng-model="test.optional" />
  <span>this checkboxs directive will uncheck it when the first one is unchecked, but the model doesn't get updated, not it's {{test.optional}}</span>
</div>
```

Controller (for defaults options):

```
$scope.test = {
  dependency: true,
  optional: false
}
```

Directive:

```
restrict: 'A',
link: function(scope,elem,attrs){
  scope.$watch(attrs.dependent,function(val){
    if (!val){
      elem[0].checked = false;
      elem[0].disabled = true
    } else {
      elem[0].disabled = false
    }
  })
}
```

EDIT: Right, [here's](http://plnkr.co/edit/ckhnLTcZIRkfd81M55wF?p=preview) the plunk.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since you're applying a directive to an element which already uses the `ng-model` directive, you need to tell `ng-model` to update the model and the view:

```
app.directive('dependent', function(){
  return {
    restrict: 'A',
    require: 'ngModel', // Requires the NgModelController to be injected
    link: function(scope,elem,attrs, ngModelCtrl){
      scope.$watch(attrs.dependent, function(val){
        if (!val) {
          elem[0].disabled = true;
          ngModelCtrl.$setViewValue(); // Updates the model
          ngModelCtrl.$render();       // Updates the view 
        } else {
          elem[0].disabled = false
        }
      });
    }
  }
});
```

Plunker [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/DtwgdNHUkrW2ilUTkToX?p=preview).

Check out the [NgModelController documentation](http://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng.directive%3angModel.NgModelController) for more details.